# Changing the name of automatic primary key field in Django

Tags: django, model, primary-key

By default, Django gives each model the following field:

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

This is great and convenient. However, I would like to know whether it is possible to change the name of the *id* field to more informative name, e.g., *item_id*.
If this is indeed possible, how can I do that?

EDIT: From the answers I understand that it is impossible to do it without setting the primary key explicitly (which is what I wanted to know).

My model has many classes, and I think that it will be clearer to give more informative field names. Does it really matter?

Comment: Directly from your link: "If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column."

Comment: @user2896976 I will clarify the question. Thanks!

Comment: I'll just go on record for a moment and say that the `id` field is a standard. If you have a field common across several models it's better to be consistent with naming. Same applies for fields like `created_at` or `updated_at`, if you choose to use those.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just reference the [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)!

> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify
>   `primary_key=True` on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve
>   explicitly set `Field.primary_key`, it won’t add the automatic `id`
>   column.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Just to make your answer cocmpleted - In your opinion, is it better to do give more informative name or just use the same "id" in all of the classes/tables (although they mean different things)?

Comment: My bet is to go with the same "id". It is a good practice since almost 99% of the time all the models will have a primary key (named *id*). The *mean different things* part will determined by the object it is called, i.e: `product.id`, `cart.id`, `volunteer.id` etc.

Comment: Isn't `product.id` better that `product.product_id` ? You got the point!

Comment: I thought about SQL statements that contains item.item_id == something.item_id (rather than item.id == something.item_id). Anyway - I get your point. =)

Comment: Given how these comments went, I prefer `item.item_id` over `item.id` because then I can construct my JOINS with USING.

Comment: This can be useful if you use an underscore naming convention in an established database, but need to integrate tables from a system with snake case primary keys (e.g. "Id"). That way you can retain extant queries for these tables (and their foreign keys) instead of renaming all the columns. In practice this rarely causes a headache long-term.

Comment: Using item_id instead of item.id allows to use JOINS: SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 without   "column "id" specified more than once" problems ;D